# Does feeling weak mean one should stop a workout?

Tags: weighttraining

If I'm partway through a workout and not feeling "bad," but weight that was recently easy is feeling hard, is the workout entirely a waste (meaning I should just stop), or is it worth my time to complete the workout with lower weights than I might normally use?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean stopping the whole training session or just ending the current set and moving on to the next exercise with lower weights? Why would you lower weights on lat pulldowns if you felt weak on bench press, for example?

Comment: Stopping the whole training session.

Comment: Are all weights feeling weak to you on all exercises and thats why you stopped? I generally call these bad days, and they are common. Every now and then you have a random bad workout day, and it can mean you plateaued, but generally means you didnt get enough sleep, enough calories from last workout, enough energy, your diet that day mightve been bad, had a high fat meal before working out which slows you down, not enough water or good carbs throughout the day, etc.. Finish the workout, even if its depressing, and be prepared for the next. working out doesnt stop with the gym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work your muscles, of course they get tired!

Feeling progressively weaker is to be expected during a workout, and as long as you can safely perform your exercises there's no reason to stop. You could even argue that if you're *not* feeling weaker towards the last set you're doing something wrong.

There's also no reason why all sets should be the same weight, there's even a training principle called [Reverse Pyramid Training](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/articles/reverse-pyramid-training) which you start out heavy and decrease weight. (There's also [German Volume Training](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/german-volume-training-programs.html) in which you do lots of "light" sets, and believe me when I say that those last sets are anything but light.)

Having said this, there could still be room for improvement in how you work out.

First of all, [lifting to failure isn't necessary](https://theconversation.com/training-to-failure-debunking-claims-this-popular-weightlifting-technique-is-the-most-effective-for-building-muscle-and-strength-173872) and can even be counterproductive, since it causes a lot of fatigue. Staying a few (say, 2-3) reps shy of fail gives good results and lets you do more total work.

Second, consider how long you rest between sets. [Numbers](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/how-long-should-you-rest-between-sets.html) [often](https://www.healthline.com/health/fitness/rest-between-sets) [cited](https://www.verywellfit.com/beginners-guide-to-sets-repetitions-and-rest-intervals-3498619) is that for strength, rest 2-5 minutes between sets, and for building muscle, 30-90 seconds; however there's at least [one study showing that longer rest can give better muscle growth](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26605807/).

Practically, if you're lifting to look better and be stronger, I'd recommend longer rest (at least 2 minutes) for compound exercises such as squat, bench press, deadlift, bent-over row, etc., to allow for good form and more reps at a heavier weight, and then finish off with short rest for isolation exercises like leg extensions, curls, and pushdowns to save time and get that nice pump. (If you're training to be an elite bodybuilder or powerlifter the optimal rest length will be different, but then you'd already know this.)